# Spring Batch for processing large CSV file

Tags: java, spring, csv, inputstream, spring-batch

I have a 5gb CSV file that I am trying to process with Spring Batch (read, process, write to db).  What is the best way to go about this keeping in mind that I have requirements to not use any XML config, to NOT split the file into smaller files, and all records must be processed in order?  Does Spring Batch have the ability to process and write data while it is being streamed from the source?  Is there any way to tell Spring Batch to read X lines from the file, process, and write (commit) and then grab the next X lines from the file while keeping track of which lines it has already processed?

Comment: did you read SB documentation before post your question?

Comment: Yes.  Their examples are all overly-simplistic and include lots of XML config - both of which are not helping me at all solve this issue.  I have bashed my head against a wall for over 2 weeks now trying to get this to work.  The reader quits after only reading 50 or so records.

Comment: With SB you can do all the things you are asking for. Buy a book or search for more docs around the net; your question is too generic to have a specific answer

Comment: Those simple samples, as you call them, have exactly the one you are looking for (although the file they read isn't as large as 5gb but the proces is still the same).

Comment: What you are describing is what Spring Batch does.  Have you looked at the Spring Batch guide found here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ ?  It does exactly what you're asking for.